# Special char key pressed event called to often

Tags: java, keyboard

I'm programming a program where it's important to have access to many keyboard keys.
I add an `KeyListener` to the actual window. Now if the user presses an alphanumeric key on the keyboard the event `keyPressed` gets called once, how it also should be.
But if the user presses for example a dot, or another special char, the `keyPressed` event gets called very very often (as long as the key is hold down, it countinues to call the event)

If you want to know: I'm using Mac Os Lion 10.7.2 and Java 6.0.

Is it possible to avoid that often calling of the event?

Comment: please make your question more intelligible

Comment: I hope that it's now better...

Comment: See [this](http://omtlab.com/java-swing-key-event/) all key event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are bound to give results like this coz for <kbd>_</kbd> to appear you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, so a `keyPressed(...)` event is fired for <kbd>Shift</kbd> key too. Better use [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), for this scenario. Many keys like <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Escape</kbd> will act differently than intended, with `KeyListeners`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at this. But I don't need special chars which require more than one key to enter them. If there's no other way I'll do this like that, but it would mean that I have to rewrite very much code...